# NGINX Reverse Proxy Not working with www url

Tags: nginx, centos, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setup on Cent OS 7 and it's working well but the issue I just now noticed is that my domains will not work if you go to [www.foo.foo.com](http://www.foo.foo.com) but do work going to foo.foo.com.

my config looks like this:

**foo.foo.com.conf**

```
     server {
    server_name foo.foo.com;
    set $upstream 10.10.1.12:8012;

    location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass https://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
    server {
    if ($host = foo.foo.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name foo.foo.com;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

**[www.foo.foo.com.conf](http://www.foo.foo.com.conf)**

```
     server {
    server_name www.foo.foo.com;
    set $upstream 10.10.1.12:8012;

    location / {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass https://$upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
    server {
    if ($host = foo.foo.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.foo.foo.com;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    include /etc/nginx/sites/*.conf;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }
}
```

My question is how do I go about making the reverse proxy resolve using www. and not using www.? I attempted to make 2 .conf files for each domain as in one foo.foo.com.conf and a [www.foo.foo.com.conf](http://www.foo.foo.com.conf) but that seem to not be the right way to go about it as the issue is not resolved with this.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any blatantly obvious problems with the configuration. Check your DNS records.

Comment: I have a DNS A record for www to the WAN IP of my reverse proxy so I assume that's all I would need. I guess the conf file (www) I posted is the correct way to go about this though? If so I can keep messing with it.

Comment: You'll need the configuration, yes. But are you sure about the DNS A record? I don't see one for www.hydro.hydradynetech.com.

Comment: As @MichaelHampton said, www.foo.foo.com doesn't resolve.  Also, "    if ($host = foo.foo.com)"  looks improbable inside "server { servername www.foo.foo.com; }.

Comment: In the server block for www.foo.foo.com you do an if host = foo.foo.com. Should that be if host = www.foo.foo.com?